# Update List with Loop Arguments Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, list, for-loop, updating

I'm trying create new random List based on other List. But this code doesn't work to update the var

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.math

val randSymbol = List(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,8)
val _finalSymbol = List(List(0,0,0,0,0),List(0,0,0,0,0),List(0,0,0,0,0))
    var i:Int = 0
    var a:Int = 0
    for (i <- 0 to 2){
      _finalSymbol(i) = new List
      for (a <- 0 to 4){
        var iRandIndex = floor(Random.nextInt() * randSymbol.length).toInt
        var iRandSymbol = randSymbol(iRandIndex)
        _finalSymbol(i)(a) = iRandSymbol
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
val _finalSymbol = (0 to 2) map { _ => Random.shuffle(randSymbol).take(5) }
```

And do yourself a favor: buy a scala book. 
It's not javascript. At all.

Comment: Sure I will buy them, I've tried this, but this one is indexed sequence, and how do I convert this to List[List[Int]] ?

Comment: So this works for me: `List(_finalSymbol(0),_finalSymbol(1),_finalSymbol(2))`, but can I do something very simple?

Comment: try `_finalSymbol.toList`

Comment: Why do you care if it is a list or not? You should not. It doesn't matter for most cases you care about.
If you want it to be a list for some reason, add `.toList` at the end as @TzachZohar suggested, or replace `(0 to 2)` with `List(1,2,3)` ... But that's just a waste of ticks. You don't need it.